# Cut data at given value

Tags: python, function

Hei

I tried to cut a data set at a given value. I want to get a new set only containing the data from index 0 till the index where the values in the data get bigger than the given value --> data[0:i]. (I made sure, with another function, that the data contains each value only once and that they are sorted from smallest to biggest.)

```
 def identify_lower_region(dat, max_value, dist=1.):
        """Identify upper region in meassurement 

    Arguments:
        dat {dataframe} -- Dataframe with two meassurements (e.g. height and pressure)

    Keyword Arguments:
        max_value{int} -- maximum value of observation interval
       
    """
    press= dat.query("`High`<@max_value")['Pressure']

    return press
```

The error I get.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do I have to set a defautl to the max_value, as it could be that the exact max_value does not occure in the data set? And how do I fix the syntax? I use python 3.7

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation of your code is wrong as you have a mismatch between the indentation of your docstring and the rest of the code.

The following does not give me a syntax error.

```py
def identify_lower_region(dat, max_value, dist=1.0):
    """Identify upper region in meassurement

    Arguments:
        dat {dataframe} -- Dataframe with two meassurements (e.g. hight and pressure)

    Keyword Arguments:
        max_value{int} -- maximum value of observation interval
        dist {float} -- distance window of peak finding
    """
    press = dat.query("`High`<@max_value")["Pressure"]

    return press
```

Comment: Could it be that the values of "High" are saved as string and max_value is given as int? So how could I include a change from str to int for all the values?

Comment: I don't have enough information about what `dat` is and what `query` does. At the moment what is happening is that your string is treated as a string literal, meaning the text in sent into that function is treated as the raw text. Try  `press = dat.query(f"\`High\`<@{max_value}")["Pressure"]` to see if explicitly inserting the value of `max_value` would work.